# Display bitmap images (.bmp) stored in database on web page

Tags: php, image, mysqli

I am faced with the task of retrieving image data that was stored as longblob in a MySQL database.
The php script i am using throws errors saying that the image can not be displayed because it contains errors.

Below is my php script:

```
   $sql = "SELECT Form FROM Forms WHERE id = XXXX";
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
   {
       header('Content-Type:image/bmp');
       echo $row['Form'];
   }
```

Need Help

Comment: Are you certain the image is truly a bmp and not a jpg or something else?

Comment: If you view the source for the page, do you see the binary string for the image, or is it blank?

Comment: The error reads :"the image http://localhost/hope/image_test.php" cannot be displayed beacuse it contains errors.

Answer (score 1):

- You are missing close quotes on L1 of your SQL.
- In your loop, you are sending the header then sending output and repeating this. That will cause errors. Please send the Content-Type header ONCE and THEN stream your output. Send the header OUTSIDE your loop.

Comment: @ewom2468: In the original code you posted, you were missing the ending quote after your SQL query. @xdazz edited the question and added the ending quote, but it looks like he put it after the `;`. So from the code he edited (which is what is now showing in your post), you need to either add another `;` at the end of the `$sql` line or move the `;` from inside the quotations to the end of the line.